# Function dashboardPagePlus() is not compatible with latest shinydashboardPlus version

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

I use the exact code from [here](https://rinterface.com/shiny/shinydashboardPlus/) to run the shinydashboardPlus. But when I try to run the app I get: `could not find function "dashboardPagePlus"`. I tried the CRAN and the github version with

```
# for the CRAN version
install.packages("shinydashboardPlus")
# for the latest version
devtools::install_github("RinteRface/shinydashboardPlus")
```

and my sessionInfo is:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinydashboardPlus_2.0.0 shinydashboard_0.7.1     shiny_1.6.0             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5      withr_2.3.0     packrat_0.5.0   digest_0.6.26   later_1.1.0.1   mime_0.9       
 [7] R6_2.4.1        lifecycle_0.2.0 xtable_1.8-4    magrittr_2.0.1  rlang_0.4.9     promises_1.1.1 
[13] ellipsis_0.3.1  tools_4.0.4     httpuv_1.5.4    fastmap_1.0.1   compiler_4.0.4  htmltools_0.5.1
```

but it does not work. I tried to run in [rstudio cloud](https://rstudio.cloud/projects) and it works but there is used the `shinydashboardPlus_0.7.5` version. How can I find and install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `shinydashboardPlus` version you are using locally (both from CRAN and Github) is version 2.0.0 (as stated in your `SessionInfo`) and the function `dashboardPagePlus` is no longer in this new version (it was in earlier versions e.g. 0.7.5, hence why the example runs on this version on the cloud which has not been updated).

So the example you [refer to](https://rinterface.com/shiny/shinydashboardPlus/) is now outdated as it uses old functions that now do not feature in 2.0.0 (I will open an issue on Github as I would also like a new reproducible example!).

There has been a major re-write of the package - see https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/shinydashboardPlus.html and https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/news/index.html for more details.

You can download and browse old package versions from their [Github repo](https://github.com/RinteRface/shinydashboardPlus) but I would not advise doing so as you will run into backward compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you advice me not to use shinydashboardPlus at all, cause I wanted to use functions like the one for right sidebar.

Comment: By all means use the package. It looks great. Just use version 2.0.0 with the newer functions. The right sidebar is still there it has been re-named and re-coded. According to the link above I provided the old `rightSidebar()` component has become `dashboardControlbar()`.

Comment: See the very basic example at the bottom of [this page](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/shinydashboardPlus.html).